# Printing a pyramid pattern of a 2D list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D list as shown below.

```
   Board = [[1],
             [1,2,3],
             [1,2,3,4,5],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
```

What i want to do is to print this list in a pyramid/triangle like structure.

It should look like this:

```
                 1
           1     2     3
     1     2     3     4     5
1    2     3     4     5     6     7
```

I'm using this board in my program for a game that i want to make. 
I searched through a couple of other questions, and most of them displayed the pyramid using simple characters(i.e "*"). **I want to display the pyramid using the contents within the 2D list**. I can't seem to find a way to do it...

Is there any way i could print out the list above in this format/structure???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate through `Board` and append `len(Board) - current_index` many tabs to the beginning of the line;

```
>> board_length = len(Board)
>> for i, b in enumerate(Board):
>>     print("\t"*(board_length - i - 1) + "\t".join(str(x) for x in b))
```

Results in;

```
                        1
                1       2       3
        1       2       3       4       5
1       2       3       4       5       6       7
```